# get host WITH PORT from request

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to redirect to the original page after a login redirect.  I have some middleware which checks if the user is logged in and if not redirects to the login page. code below

```
middlewareObj.isLoggedIn = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect("/login");
};
```

I am trying to get the full url from the request and tack it on the the end of the login URL so that after the login, I can redirect.  According to the nodejs. docs I should be able to pull this info using req.host + req.originalURL.  However, when I do that, it just pulls the hostname without pulling the port.  in other words, it just returns localhost/pathname instead of localhost:3000/pathname. node js docs say that req.host should return the port while req.hostname should return just the hostname, but I'm getting the same output either way.

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodejs express: hostname with port from the req object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879532/nodejs-express-hostname-with-port-from-the-req-object)

Answer (score 0):

`req.header('Host')` should get the HTTP Host header which will contain the port.